# Checkbox not returning checked

Tags: php, checkbox

I have the following code:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" name="fhaac_publicly_queryable" value="<?php
    if (isset( $_POST ['fhaac_publicly_queryable'])) {
        echo  "checked";
    } elseif ($fhaac_publicly_queryable == "on") {
    echo "checked";
    }
?>" name="fhaac_publicly_queryable" /> Publicly Queryable on a search</div>
```

I have the content saving to the database, but on save, the checked check box disappears and I can't figure out how to query so it returns. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do not use `$fhaac_publicly_queryable` as variable name unless you explicitely created such. Lookup `$_POST`/`$_GET`/`$_REQUEST` instead

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the `checked` attribute as the value of the `value` attribute. Plus, the `name` attribute is written twice. Do this instead:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fhaac_publicly_queryable" <?php
if (isset($_POST['fhaac_publicly_queryable'])){
    echo 'checked';
} else if($fhaac_publicly_queryable == "on"){
    echo "checked";
}?>>
    Publicly Queryable on a search
</div>
```

I still encourage you to please do the PHP logic somewhere else, because this just looks awful. It really does. And to edit your if/else, it could be improved with `or` (`||`).